# VideoView MediaController style problems

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I have a situation where I am streaming a video using a `standard VideoView` in combination with a `MediaController object`. Everything works as far as playback is concerned, however the appearance of the `ProgressBars` for when the video is loading have the appearance of an earlier version of android.

I had a similar problem with `ProgressBars`, but this was solved by `changing the style` of the progress bar from `"Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"` to "`Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal"`

Is there anything similar for a `VideoView`?

Currently I have:

[image: The old Android appearance that I don't want]

But I would like to have something similar to:

[image: The new appearance which I would like]

These screens are from a Nexus 4 running KitKat.

Thanks

Comment: What API you are using???VideoView depends on the latest API.

Comment: I'm currently using API level 19, with my Manifest containing as follows: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define a Holo style for the activity in your manifest or make your own extending it.
For example:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.MyPlayerActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"/>
```

Comment: Quick note that the theme mentioned is only for API 11 and higher.